# android not getting calls on the other side when using gcm and sinch sdk

Tags: android, sinch

I'm trying to use gcm to start calls in sinch, I send the push notification and I get it on the other side but when I try to start a call I get null pointer exception in my service at `mCall.addCallListener( );`

this is the part of the gcm intent service where I get the notification and start sinch service :

```
{
            String callId = intent.getExtras().getString("callId");
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, SinchClientService.class);
            intent3.setAction(SinchClientService.ACTION_START_CALL);
            intent3.putExtra(SinchClientService.INTENT_EXTRA_CALLID, callId);
            startService(intent3);
        }
```

this is what I do in the sinch service:

```
else if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_START_CALL))
            {
                String callId = intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_CALLID);
                if(callId != null)
                {
                    startCall(callId);
                }
            }

public void startCall(String callId) {
        if (mCallClient != null) {
            Call call = mCallClient.getCall(callId);
            CurrentCall.currentCall = call;

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }
```

and this is how I start sinch client:

```
private void startSinchClient(String id, String userName) {
        mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(id).
                applicationKey(APP_KEY).applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

        mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);

        mSinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
        mSinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
        mSinchClient.setSupportPushNotifications(true);

        mSinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(false);
        //mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();

        mMessageClient = mSinchClient.getMessageClient();
        mMessageClient.addMessageClientListener(this);

        mCallClient = mSinchClient.getCallClient();
        mCallClient.addCallClientListener(this);

        mSinchClient.checkManifest();
        mSinchClient.start();
    }
```

and this is my onIcommingCall method:

```
@Override
    public void onIncomingCall(CallClient client, Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Incoming call");

        CurrentCall.currentCall = call;


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
```

and this is the part of my call service where I get null pointer exception:

```
if(CurrentCall.currentCall == null)
            stopSelf();

        mCall = CurrentCall.currentCall;
        mCall.addCallListener(this);
```

Note: my call service implements call listener

I never get the call, can someone help me?

**Edit** this is how I initialize a call:

in the sinch service:

```
public void callFriend(String id) {
        if (mCallClient != null) {
            Call call = mCallClient.callUser(id);
            CurrentCall.currentCall = call;

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }
```

in the call service:

```
@Override
    public void onShouldSendPushNotification(Call call, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Should send push notification");
        Log.d("payload", pushPairs.get(0).getPushPayload());

        asyncTask = new sendPushNotifications(this, call.getRemoteUserId(), pushPairs, call.getCallId());
        asyncTask.execute();
    }

    class sendPushNotifications extends AutoAsyncTask {

        List<PushPair> pushPairs;

        String message;

        String senderId;
        String message_id;
        String time_stamp;
        String callId;

        public sendPushNotifications(Context context, String senderId, List<PushPair> pushPairs, String callId) {
            super(context, false);

            this.pushPairs = pushPairs;
            this.senderId = senderId;
            this.callId = callId;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            boolean connectedToInternet = connManager.getNetworkInfo( ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()
                    || connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected();
            if (connectedToInternet) 
            {   
                String regId;
                //JSONArray arrayList = new JSONArray();

                for(PushPair p: pushPairs)
                {
                    regId = new String(p.getPushData());
                    //arrayList.put(regId);

                    UserFunctions.sendCallPushNotifications(senderId, regId, "call", callId);
                }

                asyncTask = null;
                return 0;
            } 
            else 
            {
                asyncTask = null;
                return 1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result == 0) 
            {
                Log.d("call push sent", "sent");
            } 
            else if (result == 1) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No Network Connection !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error occured,Please Try Again Later !!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**latest edit** so I did what you said and I only get calls in the messaging activity, my new codes are:

in the call service:

```
@Override
    public void onShouldSendPushNotification(Call call, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Should send push notification");
        Log.d("payload", pushPairs.get(0).getPushPayload());

        asyncTask = new sendPushNotifications(this, call.getRemoteUserId(), pushPairs, call.getCallId());
        asyncTask.execute();
    }

    class sendPushNotifications extends AutoAsyncTask {

        List<PushPair> pushPairs;

        String message;

        String senderId;
        String message_id;
        String time_stamp;
        String callId;

        public sendPushNotifications(Context context, String senderId, List<PushPair> pushPairs, String callId) {
            super(context, false);

            this.pushPairs = pushPairs;
            this.senderId = senderId;
            this.callId = callId;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            boolean connectedToInternet = connManager.getNetworkInfo( ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()
                    || connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected();
            if (connectedToInternet) 
            {   
                String regId;
                String payload;
                //JSONArray arrayList = new JSONArray();

                for(PushPair p: pushPairs)
                {
                    regId = new String(p.getPushData());
                    payload = new String(p.getPushPayload());
                    //arrayList.put(regId);

                    UserFunctions.sendCallPushNotifications(senderId, regId, "call", callId, payload);
                }

                asyncTask = null;
                return 0;
            } 
            else 
            {
                asyncTask = null;
                return 1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result == 0) 
            {
                Log.d("call push sent", "sent");
            } 
            else if (result == 1) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No Network Connection !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error occured,Please Try Again Later !!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

the gcm intent service:

```
else
        {
            String callId = intent.getExtras().getString("callId");
            String payload = intent.getExtras().getString("payload");
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, SinchClientService.class);
            intent3.setAction(SinchClientService.ACTION_START_CALL);
            intent3.putExtra(SinchClientService.INTENT_EXTRA_CALLID, callId);
            intent3.putExtra(SinchClientService.INTENT_EXTRA_PAYLOAD, payload);
            startService(intent3);
        }
```

the sinch service:

```
else if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_START_CALL))
            {
                String callId = intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_CALLID);
                if(callId != null)
                {
                    startCall(callId);
                }
            }

public void startCall(String callId) {
        /*if (mCallClient != null) {
            Call call = mCallClient.getCall(callId);
            CurrentCall.currentCall = call;

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }*/
        if(INTENT_EXTRA_PAYLOAD != null)
        {
            if(mSinchClient.isStarted())
            mSinchClient.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(INTENT_EXTRA_PAYLOAD);
            else
            {
                DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
                UserInfo info = handler.getUserDetails();
                startSinchClient(String.valueOf(info.uid), info.name);

                String gcm_regId = ChatDatabaseHandler.getInstance(this).getGcmRegId();

                mSinchClient.registerPushNotificationData(gcm_regId.getBytes());
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onIncomingCall(CallClient client, Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Incoming call");
        /*if(INTENT_EXTRA_CALLID != null)
        {
        CurrentCall.currentCall = mCallClient.getCall(INTENT_EXTRA_CALLID);
        INTENT_EXTRA_CALLID = null;
        }*/
        CurrentCall.currentCall = call;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
```

that is also what I do when I bind and unbind with the service:

```
@Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        mSinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        return mServiceInterface;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing the code where you actually send the Sinch-specific payload in your push, you should use `PushPair.getPushPayload()` to retrieve it in the `onShouldSendPushNotification` callback and make sure to include that in the push message.
 After you add that, you need to retrieve the payload on the receiver side and pass in to `relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(String payload)`. This will give you the `onIncomingCall` callback on the receiver side.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why would I need the push payload if I successfully send the call id and retrieve it on the other side then I send it to the sinch service then I deal with it?

Comment: @KareemEssamGaber Please see https://www.sinch.com/docs/android/user-guide/#pushnotifications where it is explained what you need to do on both the caller and the callee side. The payload is necessary for the client to be able to initiate everything needed internally in the SinchClient.

Comment: I still have one problem, I get the call only when I'm in the messaging activity where I set the service to start listening on active connection, but when I close the messaging activity also where I stop listening on active connection I don't get the call, I have posted some code to let you see my latest edit

Comment: Are you sure the call to `relayRemotePushNotificationPayload` is actually done? You can also verify it works by inspecting the return value from relayRemotePushNotificationPayload and making sure it is a call, and has the expected callId.

Comment: I tried everything but I still don't get the call,can you tell me what do I have to do after calling sinchClient.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload( ), do I have to set anything in onIncomingCall?, do I have to call mCallClient.getCall( )?